# how to use cron jobs in a laravel 5 project

Tags: cron, laravel-5

I have been trying to use cron job in laravel 5 project but not at all successfull tried using SCHEDULER commands but still no help. but first of all wanna run the scheduler command manually.

but it returns no such command found.

Answer (score 0):

If your intention is to test a console command before scheduling it to laravel Kernel (which is invoked by the crontab):

Once you set up your console command, e.g. via command line in your laravel project folder :

```
 $php artisan make:console Test
```

Artisan will create your class to manage this console command in

[..]app/Console/Commands/Test.php

Then you can execute the command manually via console :

```
 $php artisan Test
```